# Visual studio git sync throwing error

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015

In visual studio 2015, When I `commit and sync` a change I get the following error

`Unable to sync because the current branch does not track a remote branch. Publish the branch to sync changes with the remote.`

But I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: you need to set up a git remote server. go to any folder where you want that to be and from the git console run the following command: git init --bare "Name.git". then go where you want your working files to be and clone that repository, copy your files, and than add them, commit and sync. Back to your error, when you add and commit files, you do that on your local repository, but the sync goes out and sync your files with the server / remote repository. Since you don't have one set up you get the specified error. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to push your changes to git you first need to create the branch on the remote server holding your repository. Assuming that you have set up a repository and connected visual studio to it, open Team Explorer, hit home (the "House" button), click "Sync" and then "Publish".

If you have not set up the repository yet, you first need to do that. Open Team Explorer, click "Manage connections" (the power cord plug icon) and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below work around which may help you resolve your issues.

Form Team explorer home screen:

1. Click Branches
2. Click on the drop-down at the top that has Branches | {Project Name}
3. Select Sync
4. Click Sync button

Your branch will be moved to Remote server.